# Unable to catch click event on Tabs in HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I know this is a very basic question, and I already have the logic to build the same, but I am unable to catch the `click` event on a tab. 
Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nileshforyou/18418exe/) for the same
Here is my code

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> </link>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabs, #tabs-1').tabs({
            select: function(event, ui){
                var tabNumber = ui.index;
                var tabName = $(ui.tab).text();

                alert('Tab number ' + tabNumber + ' - ' + tabName + ' - clicked');
            }
        });
    });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="text" id="text_box_id" ></input>
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <p> text in tab1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Text in tab2</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Text in tab3 </p>
      </div>
    </div>         
    </body>
    </html>
```

Am i doing anything wrong here? Did I import the libraries correctly?

Comment: Why are you including 2 versions of jQuery?

Comment: try using activate:function(event, ui) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Select is deprecated and use activate instead of select.

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7138

> In order to improve consistency within the jQuery UI suite,
>   select/selected will be renamed to activate/active across the board.
>   What this means for tabs is that the selected option will be renamed
>   to active, the select event will be renamed to beforeactivate, and the
>   show event will be renamed to activate. The beforeactivate and
>   activate options will include references to the tab and content panel
>   for the old and new tabs, similar to accordion. In addition, the
>   select method will be removed in favor of the setting the active
>   option. Lastly, the deselectable option will be removed in 1.9 since
>   it was deprecated in 1.8.

use activate

```
 $('#tabs, #tabs-1').tabs({
            activate: function(event, ui){
              var tabNumber = ui.newTab.index(); // get index
              var tabName =  ui.newTab.text();   // get name
          alert('Tab number ' + tabNumber + ' - ' + tabName + ' - clicked');
            }
        });
```

### JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/18418exe/27/

Comment: Hi.THanks a lot ! I have replaced Select with Activate and i also removed the multiple Jquery version in the definition. BUt now the problem is , it doesnt return the selected tab index.Please check the http://jsfiddle.net/nileshforyou/18418exe/19/